# How to retrieve/decode json/map from downloaded ByteStream?

Tags: flutter

I have a ByteStream downloaded from a Server, namely datas regarding the user.
Its in MySql server as

```
"username":"Neor","totalCoins":"350"
```

The truncated part of .php file that gives-away this data, is as follows:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Length:".strlen($data));
    echo $data;
```

I use ths Flutter code to download the data:

```
Future<void> downloadData() async {
var url = Uri.parse("https://example.com/mycloud.php");

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
  ..fields["user"] = "Dia";

var response = await request.send();
var stream = response.stream; }
```

On checking if the downloaded ByteStream contains anything, I've used print(stream.length), which prints out as 137.
How can I get the information I want from the ByteStream?

(If my question lacks in any way, please let me know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to use a multipart request for a simple POST. Instead use the simpler `http.post` method.

```
Future<void> downloadData() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://example.com/mycloud.php'),
    body: <String, String>{
      'user': 'Dia',
    },
  );

  final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);
  // if you want to ensure the character set used, replace this with:
  // json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
}
```

If you do stick with the stream way, you have a `Stream<List<int>>` that you want to turn initially into a `List<int>`. Use the `toList()` method on stream for that. Then you have to decode that into characters. JSON is always encoded in utf8, so you could:

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(await stream.toList()));
```

(Under the hood, `http` is basically doing that for you; collecting the stream together and doing the character decoding and presenting that as `body`.)

Comment: I'm having this error with `final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body)`:
https://pastie.io/tzjodv.groovy

Comment: Also, having similar error with `json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))`
https://pastie.io/manpyo.groovy

Comment: The server is delivering XML, not json. Try `print(response.body);` then use the `xml` package to decode it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, honestly helped me. I had some minor self-made issue, but now its working with `final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body):`. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

First
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
String foo = utf8.decode(bytes);
Then
Map valueMap = json.decode(foo );

Comment: Hello, I get this error with your suggestion: 
https://pastie.io/tuxcim.groovy

Comment: Can you send me the exact  byteStream ?

Comment: I have it solved now, thank you for your help!